# Magento 2 - Display all products on homepage

Tags: magento2, extensions, filter, product-list, home-page

I'm trying to add a overview of all products with filter on the Homepage of my Magento store. I followed the following tutorial from PHP Cuong which I got up and running.

https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-one-page-products

Currently I have a separate page with the following url "/phpcuong/product/onepage" which shows an overview of both the product filter and the products. But what I want to achieve is to have the content of this page (All products and the productfilter) to pop-up as part of my homepage.

I was not able to find any other thread about this topic. Most threads I found add products to the homepage with block shortcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module turned out to be unnecessary to my issue, the solution came from the following website in the form of xml code.

https://swissuplabs.com/blog/practical-guide-magento-and-magento-2-layered-navigation/

The following adds an overview of all filters on the homepage:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
<block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
    <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
</block>
```

The following adds an overview of all products on the homepage:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
        <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                  name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                  template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```